# Linear Search of string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, linear-search

So I have no errors in my code but for some reason my search is returning the true result no matter if the array contains it

```
public static void linSrch(String[] names) {
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Please enter search");
    String search;
    search = inputDevice.nextLine();
    boolean searchReturn;
    for (int index = 0; index < names.length - 1; index++) {
        if (names[index] == search) {
            searchReturn = true;
        }
    }
    if (searchReturn = true) {
        System.out.println(search + " is found in the array.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(search + " not found in the array");
    }
}
```

Comment: To compare if two strings are equal, do `names[index].equals(search)` instead of using `==`

Comment: Also, `if (searchReturn = true) {` does not check to see is `searchReturn` is `true`.  It **assigns** the value `true` to the variable `searchReturn`.  You want simply `if (searchReturn) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
if (names[index] == search) {
    searchReturn = true;
}
```

You have to write:

```
if (names[index].equals(search)) {
    searchReturn = true;
}
```

Because, in case of Non-primitive data types `==` checks the memory addresses are equal or not.

And also must not forget about:

```
if (searchReturn = true) {
    System.out.println(search + " is found in the array.");
}
```

to change:

```
if (searchReturn) {
    System.out.println(search + " is found in the array.");
}
```

Because, you are assigning instead of checking.

Comment: thanks, put me on the right track, i ended up revamping it and using startsWith, endWith, and contains for my needs but this steered me in the direction i needed to go! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The following  code

```
if (searchReturn = true)
```

will just assign `searchReturn` as true and will execute the code within it.

Instead of this code you should change it to

```
if (searchReturn)
```

which will run whenever `searchReturn` is true

Also to compare strrings use `equals` method instead of `==`

Comment: Or just `if (searchReturn)`, it's cleaner.